# Notice: Accessing static property DBController::$conn as non static

Tags: php

```
{

class DBController 
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = " ";
private $password = " ";
private $database = " ";

private static $conn;

function __construct() {
  $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    if(!empty($this->conn)) {
        $this->selectDB();
    }
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conn;
}

function selectDB() {
    mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->database);
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;
}
}
}
```

I have the above class of database controller but i am getting notice or warning as mentioned below:

> Notice: Accessing static property DBController::$conn as non static in C:\abc\DBController.php on line 11 ($this->conn = $this->connectDB();)

> Notice: Accessing static property DBController::$conn as non static in C:\abc\DBController.php on line 23 (mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->database);)

> Notice: Accessing static property DBController::$conn as non static in C:\abc\DBController.php on line 27 ($result  = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);)

Comment: Why do you even create a class like `DBController`? That seems like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->conn` should be `static::$conn`

*or*

remove `static` keyword from `private static $conn;`